# XPage concurrency NotesContext not initialized

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, xpages, lotus-notes

Domino version: 9.0.1
Designer version: 9.0.1
ExtLibs: 901v00_01.20131029-1400

I am using [this site as a source of information.](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-99U64Q)

**Use Case / Situation**
I have an XPage application where I want to allow the user to push a button to start a concurrent task (like creating complex documents using configuration documents etc).  I do not want the UI thread to be blocked for the time it takes for those documents to be created.  I also want this option available for future XPage applications by creating abstract classes that make things easier later.

I am using the source code from @stwissel available on the above listed website. This was the best starting point I found on google for XPage concurrency because of the abstract future-friendly way of setting up the classes.  If readers would like me to put the source code on the question I can edit the question and do so.

**The problem**
As I stated in the comments section of that website, I am having an issue getting the current context so that the session and databases etc can be fetched.

```
29.11.2013 12:47:22   HTTP JVM: Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-1" 
29.11.2013 12:47:22   HTTP JVM: java.lang.IllegalStateException: NotesContext not initialized for the thread
29.11.2013 12:47:22   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.getCurrent(NotesContext.java:123)
29.11.2013 12:47:22   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:383)
29.11.2013 12:47:22   HTTP JVM:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:638)
29.11.2013 12:47:22   HTTP JVM:     at de.holistic.utils.multithreading.AbstractBackgroundTask.run(AbstractBackgroundTask.java:29)
29.11.2013 12:47:22   HTTP JVM:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:906)
29.11.2013 12:47:22   HTTP JVM:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:929)
29.11.2013 12:47:22   HTTP JVM:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:738)
```

Again, I am only using the code on the linked website, the task that I am testing with is just a simple "create a document" kind of test thread, nothing fancy.

```
private void runNotes(){ 

        Database events = null;
        Document registration = null;

        try{
            events = notesSession.getCurrentDatabase();//notesSession is apart of the abstract class
            registration = events.createDocument();
            registration.replaceItemValue("Form", "frm_testDoc");
            registration.replaceItemValue("testField", "this is a test");
            registration.save();

        } catch (NotesException e) {
            OpenLogItem.logError(e);
        } finally {
            if(registration != null) try{registration.recycle();} catch (NotesException e) {}
            if(events != null) try{events.recycle();} catch (NotesException e) {}
        }
}
```

If anyone can give me a hand with this, I would be very grateful.  Thank you!

**EDIT -- INCLUSION OF MORE CODE**

Here is the Thread Management code which is the session bean.  It has not been changed at all.

```
public class ThreadManager implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID  = 1L;
    // # of threads running concurrently
    private static final int THREADPOOLSIZE = 10;
    private final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADPOOLSIZE);

    public ThreadManager() {
        // For use in managed beans
        System.out.println("creating HolisticThreadmanager"); //TODO delete
    }

    public void submitService(final Runnable taskDef) {
        if (taskDef == null) {
            System.err.println("submitService: NULL callable submitted to submitService");
            return;
        }

        this.service.execute(taskDef);
    }

    public boolean test(){ // TODO delete
        System.out.println("Test successful");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        if ((this.service != null) && !this.service.isTerminated()) {
            this.service.shutdown();
        }
        super.finalize();
    }
}
```

Here is the abstract class which has since been changed a bit to add more server log prints for figuring out the problem.  I also changed the session variable from private to protected so I could access the session from the runNotes() method.

```
public abstract class AbstractBackgroundTask implements Runnable {
    protected final Session notesSession;
    protected final Collection<String> callBackMessages;
    private SessionCloner sessionCloner;
    private NSFComponentModule module;

    protected Session session;

    public AbstractBackgroundTask(final Session optionalSession, final Collection<String> messageHandler) {
        this.callBackMessages = messageHandler;
        // optionalSession MUST be NULL when this should run in a thread, contain a session when
        // the class is running in the same thread as it was constructed
        this.notesSession = optionalSession;
        this.setDominoContextCloner();
    }


    public void run() {
        System.out.println("in run!"); //TODO erase
        this.callBackMessages.add("Background task run starting: " + this.getClass().toString());
        try { 
            System.out.println("about to ask if notesSession is null"); //TODO erase
            if (this.notesSession == null) {
                System.out.println("notesSession is null!"); //TODO erase
                if(this.module == null){
                    System.out.println("the module is null!!!");
                }
                NotesContext context = new NotesContext(this.module);
                NotesContext.initThread(context);
                session = this.sessionCloner.getSession();
            } else {
                // We run in an established session
                System.out.println("session established!"); //TODO erase
                session = this.notesSession;
            }
            System.out.println("about to start runNotes()"); //TODO delete
            /* Do the work here */
            this.runNotes();

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("in the run stack trace!"); //TODO delete
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (this.notesSession == null) {
                NotesContext.termThread();
                try {
                    this.sessionCloner.recycle();
                } catch (NotesException e1) {
                    System.out.println(e1.getStackTrace());
                }
            }
        }
        this.callBackMessages.add("Background task run completed: " + this.getClass().toString());
    }

    private void setDominoContextCloner() {
        // Domino stuff to be able to get a cloned session
        System.out.println("in cloner()"); //TODO erase
        if (this.notesSession == null) {
            try {
                NotesContext ncontext = NotesContext.getCurrent();
                if(ncontext == null){
                    System.out.println("ncontext is null!"); //TODO erase
                    OpenLogItem.logError(new OpenLogDummyException("NotesContext is null"));
                }
                this.module = ncontext.getModule();
                if(module == null){
                    OpenLogItem.logError(new OpenLogDummyException("Module is null"));
                    System.out.println("module is null");
                }
                this.sessionCloner = SessionCloner.getSessionCloner();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                OpenLogItem.logError(e);
                System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract void runNotes();
}
```

The worker class:

```
public class Registrator extends AbstractBackgroundTask implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4136706821621738665L;
    private final String crmDbServer = "MyServer/MyCompany/DE";
    private final String crmDbPath = "directory1\\datenbank.nsf";
    private ArrayList<String> messageFromThread = new ArrayList<String>();



    public Registrator() {
        super(null, messagesFromThread);
        System.out.println("in Registrator.const"); // TODO erase
        this.fromCRM = fromCRM;
    }

    @Override
    public void runNotes() {

        try {

            createRegistrationsFromCRM();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e){
            OpenLogItem.logError(new IllegalStateException(e));
            System.out.println("caught IllegalStateException in RunNotes()");
        }

    }

    private void createRegistrationsFromCRM(){

        System.out.println("in createRegistrationsFromCRM()!"); //TODO erase


        Database events = null;
        Database crm = null;
        Document person = null;
        Document registration = null;
        int i = 0;

        try{
            System.out.println("in try!"); //TODO erase
            if(session == null) System.out.println("session is null inside the createRegsFromCRM"); //TODO erase
            if(session != null) System.out.println("session is not null inside the createRegsFromCRM");//TODO erase
            try{
                events = session.getCurrentDatabase();
            } catch(Throwable e){
                System.out.println("error getting events " + e.getMessage() + " " + e.getCause());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(events == null) System.out.println("events is null inside the createRegsFromCRM");//TODO erase
            if(events != null) System.out.println("events is not null inside the createRegsFromCRM");//TODO erase
            System.out.println("tried to get events! events: " + events.toString()); //TODO erase
            if(events == null){
                System.out.println("getting hard coded database");
                events = session.getDatabase("MyServer/MyComp-dev/DE", "directory1\\directory2\\Datenbank_xp.nsf");
            }
            if(events == null) System.out.println("events2 is null inside the createRegsFromCRM");//TODO erase
            if(events != null) System.out.println("events2 is not null inside the createRegsFromCRM");//TODO erase 
            registration = events.createDocument();
            registration.replaceItemValue("Form", "frm_testDoc");
            registration.replaceItemValue("testField", "this is a test");
            registration.save();
        } catch (NotesException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if(person != null) try{person.recycle();} catch (NotesException e) {}
            if(registration != null) try{registration.recycle();} catch (NotesException e) {}
            if(crm != null) try{crm.recycle();} catch (NotesException e) {}
            if(events != null) try{events.recycle();} catch (NotesException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, I am calling this from a sessionScope bean, here is the current server log:

```
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM: in cloner()
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM: in Reistrator.const
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM: in run!
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM: about to ask if notesSession is null
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM: notesSession is null!
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM: about to start runNotes()
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM: in createRegistrationsFromCRM()!
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM: in try!
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM: session is not null inside the createRegsFromCRM
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM: events is null inside the createRegsFromCRM
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM: in the run stack trace!
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM: null
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM: Exception in thread "pool-21-thread-1" 
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM: java.lang.IllegalStateException: NotesContext not initialized for the thread
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.getCurrent(NotesContext.java:123)
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:383)
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:638)
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM:     at de.holistic.utils.multithreading.AbstractBackgroundTask.run(AbstractBackgroundTask.java:65)
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:906)
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:929)
02.12.2013 09:52:01   HTTP JVM:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:738)
```

Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: Post the full class. Is it running as session bean?

Comment: The current database might not work with a thread - so try with an string parameter and session.resolve

Comment: The question has been edited to include the code and the newest server log information.

Comment: I think I am going to just scrap this whole thing because even hard-coding the database name is not doing any good.  Instead, I will just create a "job document" and call a Database Agent.  I am faster in Lotusscript than Notes/Domino-java anyway.

Comment: Instead of a session cloner you can go classic and use sInitThread  btw agents unless triggered on event don't run async

Comment: that is good to know!  For some reason I did not know that! Thanks.

Comment: I get the same exception when calling `NotesContext.getCurrent()`. Has anyone gotten the sample code to work?

Comment: I believe that this sort of multi-tasking should become easier with the next release of the openNTF Domino API.

Comment: The problem in my case was that I was not getting module and session cloner in the constructor but in the `run()` method. Works now.

Comment: how do I call the Registrator class

Answer (score 1):

When you thread of a NotesTask, to my best knowledge, you loose the Session context of "current database", "current agent" - since the thread could be run from anywhere. So accessing session.currentDatabase() or session.currentAgent() will most likely throw an error bubbling up from the C core.

What worked for me: never let any Notes object cross a thread boundary. Use only native Java objects (Strings, Collections of standard objects, your own classes etc). If a database needs to be communicated between threads I use the URL to hand it over:

in the main thread:

```
  String dbURL = session.getNotesUrl();
  workerclass.setDbUrl(dbURL);
```

in the worker thread:

```
  events = (Database) session.resolve(this.dbUrl);
```

Also: make your recycling easier. Put this static function into your utility class:

```
/**
 * Get rid of all Notes objects
 * 
 * @param morituri
 *            = the one designated to die, read your Caesar!
 */
public static void shred(final Base... morituri) {
    for (Base obsoleteObject : morituri) {
        if (obsoleteObject != null) {
            try {
                obsoleteObject.recycle();
            } catch (NotesException e) {
                // We don't care we want go get
                // rid of it anyway
            } finally {
                obsoleteObject = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then replace:

```
        if(person != null) try{person.recycle();} catch (NotesException e) {}
        if(registration != null) try{registration.recycle();} catch (NotesException e) {}
        if(crm != null) try{crm.recycle();} catch (NotesException e) {}
        if(events != null) try{events.recycle();} catch (NotesException e) {}
```

with:

```
        Utils.shred(person, registration, crm, events);
```

Hope that helps. A little care needs to be taken for the currentDatabase. I found even with a cloned session recycling the nsf might blow in your main thread. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Another idea would be to wrap the code into an extra XPage and use `dojo.xhrGet()` or `dojo.xhrPost()` to start that XPage multiple times with different parameters (given by the dojo.xhrGet/dojo.xhrPost call). 
That way the worker XPages can give return values to indicate if the operation was successful, and you can display that information on the calling XPage. Furthermore, you save a lot of headache caused by using custom multithreading.

Comment: But that would require that the job be performed in javascript because dojo is a javascript library.  Or am I wrong?  Is there a Java equivilent? -- Im pretty new to JSF, and the Xpage implementation of it, so you'll have to excuse me.

Comment: No, you'll only use dojo to start another XPage in the background, have a look at the documentation regarding dojo.xhrGet or dojo.xhrPost. 
In the XPage you hook into the afterRenderResponse event and set the XPage's "rendered" property to false, see http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/How_to_output_custom_content_like_print_from_an_agent for details. 

You can use standard SSJS and Java in the XPage's afterRenderResponse event